# How do I fetch best performing ads from adwords api

Tags: ruby, google-ads-api, awql

I am trying to fetch top performing ads using attributes like impressions, clickx etc

I tried google adwords reporting api first, but reporting api do not support  `ORDER BY` clause. And I couldn't find any `AdsService` in the [service list](https://github.com/googleads/google-api-ads-ruby/tree/a01574ba9b085f59640bd56726a16d8ef13e41e3/adwords_api/lib/adwords_api/v201609). Closest I could find `AdGroupsAd` which seeems do not have attributes like impressions clicks, etc. Am I missing something ?

```
query = "SELECT Headline,AdGroupName,AdType,CampaignName, Clicks FROM AD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT ORDER BY Clicks"
CSV.parse(report_utils.download_report_with_awql(query, 'CSV'))
```

> AdwordsApi::Errors::ReportXmlError: HTTP code: 400, error type:
>   'QueryError.ORDER_BY_CLAUSE_NOT_SUPPORTED', trigger: '', field path:
>   ''

Comment: You should add the code you tried and any error at the very least.

Comment: @Kris Added code sample for AD_PERFOMENCE_REPORT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there's no way to have the Adwords API give you any entities ordered by *stats*. The reports don't support any ordering. With the services, you can order by *attributes* (e.g. alphabetically by headline for text ads), but not performance metrics.

So the only way is to download the whole report and do the ordering on your end.

Comment: That will be pretty slow, Thanks anyway